# How to select row by it's values using Xpath

Tags: xpath

Let's have an example table:

```
<table>
  <tr><td>foo</td><td>bar</td><td>xxx</td></tr>
  <tr><td>xxx</td><td>bar</td><td>baz</td></tr>
  <tr><td>foo</td><td>bar</td><td>baz</td></tr>
  <tr><td>bar</td><td>baz</td><td>foo</td></tr>
  <tr><td>foo</td><td>xxx</td><td>baz</td></tr>
</table>
```

I would like to select row with values: "foo" "bar" "baz". It's important to select this row by values and not to use absolute path (Table content will have different order each time).

Comment: Issue is similar indeed. @Impulse The Fox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
//tr[td/text()='foo' and td/text()='bar' and td/text()='baz']
```

and, if order is important:

```
//tr[td[1]/text()='foo' and td[2]/text()='bar' and td[3]/text()='baz']
```